# idiom which means rain "lightly"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I am looking for a dramatic equivalent for "drizzle". I want to write down a sentence like this:

***There was a light breeze blowing. Timid clouds gathered around and then it started to...***

P.S: Is "timid cloud" correct?

Comment: Most writers I know don't work without a [thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/synonym) close to hand.

Comment: Yes but a thesaurus would usually give you one word. I am looking for a dramatic idiom. For example, for heavy rain, I learned that you can say "rain fell down in torrents". I am looking for something similar about light rain.

Comment: Isn't light rain the opposite of dramatic?

Comment: Why not just say *'....started to rain lightly'*?

Comment: Maybe I didn't choose the right word. I meant a dramatic or slightly poetic way of talking about light rain.

Comment: *'Rain lightly'* is perfectly fine.

Comment: Thanks. I already knew that one. I am looking for something a tad poetic.

Comment: You should edit the Q to include the points you make in comments. It's not clear that you want _only_ phrases.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [source](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/rain_lightly/synonyms) the rather graphic words "*spit*" and "*moisten*" are possibilities along the standard "drizzle".

Here is an instance of use of "[started to spit](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4NMABAAAQBAJ&pg=PT82&dq=%22started+to+spit%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx_Zax48LoAhUD6RoKHbW7AH4Q6AEI1gEwEA#v=onepage&q=%22started%20to%20spit%22&f=false)".

From this [other source](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/raining_lightly.html) you can select  more terms that connote the idea in just as  graphic a fashion.

- sprinkling,  spraying,  spritzing,  peppering, dusting
- [mizzling](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mizzle), (intransitive, now regional, Britain, Canada, US) To rain in very fine drops.

---

***There was a light breeze blowing. Timid clouds gathered around and then it started [to sprinkle/sprinkling].*** ([to sprinkle](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22it%20started%20to%20sprinkle%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en))

---

*Addition*

I thought I could make up for my oversight after I read your [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/529132/idiom-which-means-rain-lightly#comment1291547_529143). I am not a native speaker but it seems to me that in the domain of fiction and even more in that of poetry, no less in English than in other languages, you are allowed a lot of freedom in the way of creating images. This is obviously an image in which different people might see different things and I do not pretend I see what is most to be remarked in it. However I suppose you mean something like "clouds invading the sky in a slow, uncertain way" and that sounds perfect to me, poetic, but a poetic tone occasionally is not forbidden in fiction.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ***[sprinkle](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sprinkle)*** could work for you?

From Lexico:

> 2. ("it sprinkles", "it is sprinkling", etc.) *North American* *[no object]* Rain very lightly.
>
>    *‘it began to sprinkle’*

In your example, it would be:

> There was a light breeze blowing. Timid clouds gathered around and then it started to *sprinkle*.

Comment: Excuse me, but could you please tell me if you are a native speaker? How does "timid clouds" sound to your ear? Does it work?

Comment: Timid clouds sounds nice.

Comment: I am a native speaker (west coast, US) and, yes, "timid clouds" sounds fine, all though, to my ear, they wouldn't produce a whole lot of rain.  Maybe "_Timid clouds gathered around and sprinkled a few drops of rain_"?  You could even say they "tentatively sprinkled" which would mean they weren't commited to raining, but were sort of testing it out to see if anyone complained.